# WooCommerce Import Products with Subcategories?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a csv file I'm trying to import into WooCommerce that contains about 500 products. I have a Category column and a SubCategory column. However, I only see one "Categories" field to map to in WooCommerce. For example, how can I import products that have a category of Widgets and also a SubCategory of Objects? I'd like to maintain the category and subcategory hierarchy.

Thanks!

Comment: The [WooCommerce product importer free plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/)

Answer (score 2):

So to import categories using the Woocommerce CSV importer, you must use the following syntax for sub-categries:

```
Main Category > Sub Category1 > Sub category2
```

So for your example, the "Categories" column in CSV would look like:

```
Widgets > Objects
```

Change your csv to include this format in the "Categories" column of the Woocommerce CSV file and you will see all your Main and sub categories reflected in your store!

Answer (score -1):

To import categories and sub-categories in WooCommerce you will need to use a comma (,) to separate multiple categories. There are two ways to maintain the hierarchy of categories in WooCommerce:

1. Add all the categories in 1 single column with a comma (,) separated values. For example: Category One, Category Two, Category Three. Once the import is completed go to the category section in the WooCommerce section and move the categories to create the hierarchy.
2. Or, you can first create all the categories in the WooCommerce category section maintaining all the hierarchy and then use those categories in the CSV file column with a comma (,) separated value.

There are many free plugins available using which you can import CSV. Once of which is: https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-export-for-woocommerce/